# Why is mac able to find some bin in PATH but not others?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, python, path

I recently upgraded Python but encountered some strange behavior: I have both /opt/homebrew/bin and /usr/local/bin in my PATH variable.

`python` was in both these directories. When I removed the one in `/usr/local/bin`, zsh starting complaining that python is not recognized command. However when I removed `pip` from `/usr/local/bin` the pip command still works fine.

I had to symlink `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` in order for it to work again. But when I did the same for pip, running `which pip` still gave the one installed in `/opt/homebrew/bin/`, whereas I was expecting the one in `/usr/local/bin` to overwrite it.

As far as variables in my PATH go, `/opt/homebrew/bin` precedes `/usr/local/bin` if that matters.

Comment: Can we [assume you've rehashed the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45735/executing-zsh-rehash-after-build) and/or closed your sessions / restarted?

Comment: I just ran rehash and restarted the terminal --  pip is still point to /opt/homebrew/bin when there is a symlink on /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Ok - that’s a good step. I’m not sure why you’re not reinstalling these both via home brew to drop them where they need to be. Since you have opt, it’s detecting an Apple Silicon Mac so why not leave it there and run those first?

Comment: You're sure you haven't installed python using the installer from python.org, as well as brew? What macOS are you on?

Comment: It's possible I installed a version of python through python.org -- I don't recall as it's been too long. when I run `brew list | grep python`, it only lists 3.10 and 3.11, but I do have `python3.9` linked to `/usr/local/bin/python3` that's being ignored by the system, i.e. when I type `python3` it runs `python3.11`. 

I'm on macOS 13.5.1